# Is it possible to wirelessly connect macbook pro to LG monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display

Is it possible to wirelessly connect macbook pro 2015 to LG ULTRAWIDE monitor? Through airplay or whatever else channel, or even through 3rd-party adapter.

Comment: Any [wireless HDMI transmitter](https://www.amazon.com/Nyrius-Transmitter-Streaming-Projector-NPCS549/dp/B009E6R89C) should work. Make sure to get a 4K one if you need that quality.

Comment: AirPlay does not work on Non-Apple products

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An AppleTV will let you Airplay to the monitor or any other device with an HDMI input. owlswipe's suggestion of a wireless HDMI transmitter is another option if you don't mind adding additional hardware to the Macbook